# Searching certain Index in the variable Explorer in Python Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

The problem is, that my list contains over a million elements and I want to see, which elements there are in the middle of this list.

Is there a search function in the Spyder variable explorer?
Or do I have to do that manual?

Thank you guys

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdyS2.png)

I only tried it manually:

```
my_list[1100000]

-> "23"
```